# Start Service before Activity in ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, testing

I'm trying to write some tests for my application.

My application performs much of it's processing through a `Service` which carries out the business logic.

To test even the smallest of my Activities I would need the `Service` to be up and running to respond to it.

My question is, how do I start a Service in the `setUp()` method of `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` when I don't have a `Context` from which to start it from without first calling `getActivity()` (which would start the Activity that requires the Service to be already started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think, "getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()" is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling `getActivity()`, start the service, and that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gabriel, but the problem was that you can't start a Service without a `Context` from which to launch it from - I've edited my Question to be more clear.